# transparent object versioning in python

Tags: python, versioning

I'd like to version objects without them knowing it.

Something like this:

```
class Versioned(object):
   ...
   def version(self):
       ...

class Foo(Versioned):

   def __init__(self, a):
      self.a = a

foo = Foo(123)
assert foo.version() == 1

foo.a = 1
foo.a = 2
foo.a = 3

assert foo.version() == 4
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  why is `foo.version()` changing?

Comment: I think something close to this could be accomplished by overriding `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` to increment a per-instance counter when called. However, I'm having a hard time thinking of a situation where this would be genuinely useful.

Comment: @mgilson Because `foo`, which started at version 1 has changed 3 times.

Comment: @senderle, when there is more than one source of change, versioning can be quite useful :)

Comment: @Srg -- What about functions which mutate the object?  Do those mutations count as 1 version per function call, or 1 version per attribute changed?  Also, what about mutable objects?  Do you want to increment the version counter if you append something to a list?

Comment: @mgilson -- you're right this can get rather complex, but I was actually planning on keeping timestamps, which are absolute, rather than versions. I've used version here for simplicity.

Comment: @Srg -- That doesn't change my question.  If you change the class 6 times in a method, do you want to update the timestamp 6 times or 1 (I suppose you're saying it doesn't matter how many times you change it since you only care about *when* it changed)?  And the case where you append to a list is very difficult to do if you want to cover that case.

Comment: @mgilson -- I could calculate check-sum of the object and make a new stamp when check-sum changes..

Comment: @Srg -- But then you need to know when to calculate the check-sum ... You can't add that to `__getattr__` because after `__getattr__` has completed, the object that was retrieved hasn't changed yet.

Comment: If we're talking about that much level of control, I would make the `Versioned` class a metaclass that wraps all built-in types with my modified ones, which keep track of all the mutations. Admittedly this goes a bit too far though :)

Comment: @mgilson -- The plan is to stamp things on-store. I'll pick up an object, work with it, then store. If the object changed, it should have a new stamp stored with it.

Comment: @Srg -- Then you don't even need a class which tracks this stuff itself.  Just check-sum when you pick up the object, check-sum right before storing and compare.

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack:

```
class Versioned(object):
    version = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.version = 0

    def _increaseVersion(self):
        super(Versioned, self).__setattr__('version', self.version+1)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        super(Versioned, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
        self._increaseVersion()

    def __delattr__(self, attr):
        super(Versioned, self).__delattr__(attr)
        self._increaseVersion()


class Foo(Versioned):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        super(Foo, self).__init__()


foo = Foo(123)
print 'value:', foo.a
print 'version:', foo.version
foo.a = 23
print 'value:', foo.a
print 'version:', foo.version
del foo.a
print hasattr(foo, 'a')
print 'version:', foo.version
```

Outputs:

```
value: 123
version: 1
value: 23
version: 2
False
version: 3
```

Comment: I like this cleaner version, thanks! Is this a good idea to call super c'tor at the end? Why the class-scope `version` attribute?

Comment: @Srg -- Because the instance won't have a `version` yet if you don't call `Version.__init__(self)` before other `init` code.

Comment: @Srg the class-scope is my personal liking because it makes introspection of classes more explicit (you can `dir(cls)` and see all attributes without having to instanciate it, also code documentation tools like `epydoc` cannot display attributes if you only define them in `__init__`). The `super()` call at the end is to initialize `version` as a object attribute, so you can have multiple versions of your `Versioned` class and the version values wont mix up.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Versioned(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.version = 0
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'version':
            object.__setattr__(self, 'version', value)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
            object.__setattr__(self, 'version', self.version +1)
```

Example:

```
class Foo(Versioned):
    pass

f = Foo()
print f.version  # prints 0

f.a = 1
print f.version # prints 1

f.b = 3
print f.version # prints 2

f.b = 33
print f.version # prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at https://github.com/swisscom/cleanerversion. If I understood your requirements correctly, it does exactly what you are looking for.

Since we needed a somewhat persistent solution, the module builds up on Django, which allows writing these objects down to any Django-supported relational DB.